# Angular fetch data depending on dynamic url path params

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing

I am developing a small news portal in angular , where the main landing page opens in https://sampledomain.in.

Now if some clicks a news i have a another page to read the article and that page opens with the following route. I mentioned this route in module.ts
It's blank page with header and footer.
https://sampledomain.in/news/

Now i want to fetch the news content depending on the news-link-url path provided with the link.
https://sampledomain.in/news/xxxxxxx

I need to get this "xxxxxx" value inside this 'https://sampledomain.in/news/' page and need populate the data after fetching from database.

Comment: Then you should take some time and **RTFM**. https://angular.io/guide/router

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular 2 or above, this should be the solution:

```
let id = this.router.url.substr(this.router.url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)
```

then you need to add these 2 things in your ts:

```
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router) { }
```

You can do the last 2 statements only if you have import RouterModule in your app.module.ts or in your routing.module.ts, else you will get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Found the Solution : It's Parameterized routing

```
//Set routing in app.module.ts
const appRoutes: Routes = [
 { path: 'news/:urlLink', component: ArticlereaderComponent },
 { path: '', component: HomeComponent }

 ]



//Get the Value in the destination component

 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route.params.subscribe( params => {
    console.log(params.urlLink);
});
```

}

This colon thing "path: 'news/:urlLink'" doing the trick , i was unaware of this.